# Serving Static Files with Fossil SCM

Tags: fossil

I am running a fossil scm through a local directory, so when I start fossil I access it at localhost:8080, and I am trying to load a static webpage through it such as localhost:8080/mypage.html. My fossil setup is running multiple repositories through a directory. Whenever I try to add a static file with --files I can't figure out how to access them. I have tried placing my HTML file in both my repo directory and my fossil.exe directory. The command I normally run is `fossil.exe server repos/ --repolist --files '*.html'`, so I should have added my file, but not matter how I try, I cannot access. I have also tried the specific file, `--files 'mypage.html'`. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t checked this, but perhaps `--files` only works within each repository, and not in the `repolist` directory itself. You may want to ask this on the [Fossil forum](https://fossil-scm.org/forum/); the developers are fairly active over there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like '[embedded docs](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/embeddeddoc.wiki)' is wanted here.

Given a file system layout of
`~/web/fossil/repo-2/site/my-custom-page.html`

Launch fossil with:

```
cd ~/web/fossil
fossil ui repo-2
```

And browse to `https://localhost:8080/doc/ckout/site/my-custom-page.html`

Once you're happy with the pages commit them to the fossil repo as normal. Then the pages can be viewed without the **ckout** keyword:`https://localhost:8080/doc/site/my-custom-page.html`

> The "ckout" keywords means to pull the documentation file from the local source tree on disk, not from the any check-in. The "ckout" keyword only works when you start your server using the "fossil server" or "fossil ui" commands. The "/doc/ckout" URL is intended to show a preview of the documentation you are currently editing but have not yet checked in.